# Starting Outlook 2016 from MS Access 2016 VBA triggers "another program is using Outlook" and dies

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I use below code in MS Access 2016 to start an instance of Outlook 2016:

```
Dim appOutLook As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set appOutLook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If appOutLook Is Nothing Then
        Set appOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

End Sub
```

Outlook 2016 is closed when I run above code.
However, Outlook does not open.
I noticed that when I run this code, an icon shows on my task bar stating "Another program is using Outlook".
This icon shows for about 2 seconds and then disappears.
This might imply that another service is running in the background.
I did not find any services that might apply.
My outlook account is a Google account, didn't find any Google related services that might be running in the background.

To be frankly honest, I'm not sure whether this is a coding issue as in whether there is a better way using VBA to start an Outlook instance.
I'm out of clues on this one.

Comment: The warning indicates a program has started Outlook. Outlook is not automatically displayed. What error occurs in subsequent code to indicate Outlook is not open?

Comment: @niton, thanks for your reply. No error occurs. An icon appears for 'bout 2 seconds stating "Another program is using Outlook" and then disappears. I've searched high and low for any service running in the background causing this behavior. I don't think it's code related but you never can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I could be off but i think your code is confusing itself a bit. I'd start by removing the 'on error' lines because they could be hiding errors that you need to know about.

```
'On Error Resume Next
Set appOutLook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
'On Error GoTo 0
```

Here

```
If appOutLook Is Nothing Then...
```

you've already `Set` appOutlook, so it's never going to be `Nothing` and the block won't run.

I used to do this. Code is a bit old but looks like yours so I think it should work. (I used objOutlook, not appOutlook, to be consistent with its type.)

```
Dim objOutlook As Object

'See if Outlook is already open and use that.
Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

'If Err, Outlook is not open; get a new instance.
If Err <> 0 Then
    'Create the Outlook session.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

Hth.

---

New code:

```
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Debug.Print oOutlook.Application.Name
Debug.Print oOutlook.Application.ProductCode
Debug.Print oOutlook.Application.Version

Set oOutlook = Nothing
```

Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/828550/you-receive-run-time-error-429-when-you-automate-office-applications

Comment: I admit, I have to look up `On Error GoTo 0`. I can't remember how that works. I have a feeling you're doing what I'm doing in a different way.

Comment: Your code throws a 429 error, ActiveX component can't create object on GetObject. Which makes sense as there's no instance of Outlook running. To bypass this error I used On Error Resume Next. I don't think that this statement is correct: _"you've already Set appOutlook, so it's never going to be Nothing and the block won't run"_. It's going to be Nothing if there's no Outlook instance running. Anyway, I was trying to sort out a friend but I'm gonna hand in defeat. Must be something with some damn Microsoft service running on the background and I can't find any clues at all. Thanks anyway.

Comment: We might have been making it harder than necessary (old code/approach). See new code and link. At least I'm not getting the error any more (same error you mentioned, sry about that). Hopefully you won't get the "Another program is using Outlook" message.

Comment: No error message. Still getting the "Another program is using Outlook" message. I give up, thanks for trying to sort this out, much appreciated.

Comment: @wazz this is one of the rare occasions On Error Resume Next, followed closely by On Error GoTo 0 is correct. It is the standard procedure when it is unknown if Outlook is open. Here appOutLook will always be nothing at first as it is a given condition that Outlook is closed. GetObject will give an error unless bypassed. Since it is bypassed appOutLook = Nothing. By the way the service using Outlook is Access.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Private Sub Email_Click()
Dim oOutlook As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oNameSpace As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo 0
If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Shell ("OUTLOOK")
Else     'already open
MsgBox "Already Open"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Answers should not be simple snippets of code. Can you elaborate on why and how this code answers the question?